# MySQL Paging if ordered by likes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a social application to iOS, where users can post and like.

I made the app and the news feed loads post with the following factor:

- **Ordered by likes**

so the most liked post is on the top.

I am also using paging, so if the user scrolls down it loads more posts.

---

The problem is, that if meanwhile loading posts some post got more likes, then it may return not correct ordering, + some posts may be missing from the results.

---

For example, in this case paging loads only 2 posts.

**The full database:**

```
POST A: 10 likes
POST B: 8 likes
POST C: 7 likes
POST D: 6 likes
```

**Opening the app**

The app loads the following data:

```
POST A: 10 likes
POST B: 8 likes
```

Lets assume `POST C` got +10 more likes meanwhile

(Last seen post is B)

After loading more 2 posts the app has the following data:

```
POST A: 10 likes
POST B: 8 likes
POST D: 6 likes
```

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the records and they can change meanwhile, perhaps this is not the best approach. Because POST C would be the winner after +10 likes, so it will not show in the second post loading.

It would be ok for you to show it like this?

- POST A: 10 likes
- POST B: 8 likes
- POST C: 17 likes
- POST D: 6 likes

If positive, than you can make your query ordering by date,likes and not only by likes. Because, if your premise is to show it like a "likes ranking", you cant assume that the values can change meanwhile. The only way to achieve this would be by loading all the ranking once, and then paging between the records with no problem of changes meanwhile.